# data byte array size different for onPictureTaken and onPreviewFrame

Tags: android, android-camera, android-bitmap

Why is the data byte array size different for onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) and onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera). The former has the original image and hence gives me a clean image and the latter gives me a pixelated image. I am not using onPictureTaken because it does not get triggered sometimes.
If my picture size is 1600 x 1400 and screen size is 800 x 480
onPictureTaken gives me 1600 x 1400
and
onPreviewFrame gives me 800 x 480

This is my code:

```
mCamera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                int format = parameters.getPreviewFormat();
                //YUV formats require more conversion
                if (format == ImageFormat.NV21 || format == ImageFormat.YUY2 || format == ImageFormat.NV16) {
                    int w = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
                    int h = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;
                    // Get the YuV image
                    YuvImage yuv_image = new YuvImage(data, format, w, h, null);
}
```

I have been stuck with this issue for one week.

P.S. - In case of negative ratings please state the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the data byte array size different for onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) and onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera).

Because they are different images with different resolutions in different encodings. It would be a minor miracle if they *were* the same size.

> The former has the original image and hence gives me a clean image and the latter gives me a pixelated image

Preview frames are generally of lower quality, because they need to be captured at a high rate of speed.

> I am not using onPictureTaken because it does not get triggered sometimes

While I have encountered many problems with the camera APIs, that is not one of them.

> onPreviewFrame gives me 800 x 480

You specify the preview resolution in [`setPreviewSize()` on `Camera.Parameters`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewSize%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: is there a way to convert the encoded onPreviewFrame array to onPictureTaken ? and also the maximum supported preview size is  800 x 480. In gingerbread sometimes very rarely onPictureTaken is not triggered.

Comment: @Rohit_Ramkumar: "is there a way to convert the encoded onPreviewFrame array to onPictureTaken ?" -- `onPictureTaken()` is a method. There is no way to take a preview image and convert it into a Java method. "and also the maximum supported preview size is 800 x 480" -- perhaps on your device, but preview sizes vary by device.

Comment: The only solution is onPictureTaken() ? i Am trying to take pictures of documents and upload them. Hence the documents must be readable.

Comment: @Rohit_Ramkumar: "The only solution is onPictureTaken() ?" -- if your concern is the low-quality preview image, then yes, that is what `onPictureTaken()` is for.