# How to transfer the image by Intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I connected to the camera via API. When a function

```
camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
```

returns an array of byte [] data. If I understand correctly, this is our picture. How can I pass this array of bytes by Intent and set the resulting image next Activiti?

Comment: The `byte[] data` is in the format specified by `Camera.properties` (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getPictureFormat%28%29). You need to convert it to some kind of picture object to be able to pass it to another activity. The first step (converting) can be e.g. be done this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727335/data-byte-array-size-different-for-onpicturetaken-and-onpreviewframe

Comment: ok, but i still don't understand how convert array of byte. May i convet it in Bitmap? And sent bitmap`to another activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have success whit this way
First part

```
public void takePicture(View view) {
    camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AcceptNotAccept.class);
            intent.putExtra("picture", data);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

and then got this Intent

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_accept_not_accept);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivForAcceptPicture)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data.length());
```

Then assuming the data you want to pass implements Serializable(which it should), passing it through an Intent should be as simple as:
from one activity:

```
i.putExtra("image", bitmap);
startActivity(i);
```

into the next next activity:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bitmap data = (Bitmap)i.getSerializableExtra("image");
```

Comment: i have success with this way https://github.com/alekseytimoshchenko/CameraAndroid.git

Comment: but when it show image it's ok, but when i take a picture and send it in anouther activity and set it imageview it reversed...

Comment: I did not use the takePicture functionality but I'm guessing it might be regarding the orientation of the phone: getResources().getConfiguration().orientation

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to save the image into your External/Internal memory (prefer: External like SD) and use the full path of the image e.g.

```
Intent i = new Intent(...);
i.putExtra("myimage","path://example.path/image.jpg");
startActivity(i);
```

The receiving activity can get the image by calling its path:

```
String imagePath =  getIntent().getStringExtra("myimage");
```

Comment: i have success with this way https://github.com/alekseytimoshchenko/CameraAndroid.git

Comment: i have success with this way https://github.com/alekseytimoshchenko/CameraAndroid.git   
but when it show image it's ok, but when i take a picture and send it in anouther activity and set it imageview it reversed...

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Define "reversed"!